# React: Updating array inside State with spread operator returns 1,000X more results than needed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to update an array inside of my component's state from within a `.map()` method being run inside the `render()` method.  There are currently 9 objects within the array I'm mapping that I wish to extract a property from and add to the array inside the state. When `console.log()`ing the state to see why my page was freezing for so long I saw that it was iterating 1,000 copies of each entry.

Here's an example of one of the nine objects I'm iterating over

```
{
  "name": "Trap_808",
  "key" : "Q",
  "path": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/online-coding.appspot.com/o/drum%20samples%2Ftrap-808-08.wav?alt=media&token=c3c63635-45b0-4c99-82ff-e397f1153fa0"
}
```

Here's how I have my state defined inside the constructor.

```
this.state = { currentSound: '', triggerKeys: [] };
```

What I'm trying to do is add the `key` property from the object to the `triggerKeys` property as the objects are iterated over. This is how I'm rendering the nine objects with the `.map()` method.

```
<ul id="pad-shell">
  {
    DRUM_PATCH.map( sound =>{
      this.setState({ triggerKeys: [...this.state.triggerKeys, sound.key] });

      console.log(this.state);

      return <DrumButton
               name={sound.name}
               soundKey={sound.key}
               sourceLink={sound.path}
               trigger={this.updateSound}
             />
     });
   }
</ul>
```

I also tried updating the state like this

```
this.setState( prevState =>{ return { triggerKeys: [...prevState.triggerKeys, sound.key] } });
```

The above example is actually the one that returns 9,000 entries, the code above it returns 1,000 of the same entry.  Aside from this everything else is working as expected so I don't think there's anything else going on elsewhere in my code.  Can anyone spot what the problem is?  If you need more code let me know.

Comment: You shouldn't mutate state in render method, is an anti-pattern.

Comment: You shouldn't update the state in the render function. Every time you update the state, the component is re-rendered (unless you have a `shouldComponentUpdate` function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, you should not use `this.setState` inside of `render` - doing so will most likely cause an infinite update loop.

You haven't provided enough code context to give you a definitive answer but

*if `DRUM_PATCH` comes from props*

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { triggerKeys: props.drumPatch.map(s => s.key) }
  }


  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

*if `DRUM_PATCH` is just a constant*

```
this.state = { triggerKeys: props.drumPatch.map(s => s.key) }
```

becomes

```
this.state = { triggerKeys: DRUM_PATCH.map(s => s.key) }
```

Answer (score 1):

hey i guesss you are doing it in render function , if yes then everytime it changes the state, it will rerender and change the state again , it will be an infinite loop.

```
this.setState({ triggerKeys: [...this.state.triggerKeys, sound.key] });
```

this is the culprit